# issue when enable CORS on Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, cors

I'm trying to enable CORS on the Spring Security 4.2.3.RELEASE.
spring-mvc.xml

```
    <mvc:mapping path="/rest/**"
                 allowed-origins="*"
                 allowed-methods="GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"
                 allowed-headers="Content-Type, X-Requested-With,accept, Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization"
                 exposed-headers="Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"
                 allow-credentials="false"
                 max-age="10" />
</mvc:cors>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http pattern="/rest/**" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint" create-session="stateless">
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
        <cors/>
        <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="jwtAuthenticationFilter"/>
    </http>
```

when try to deploy:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not create CorsFilter

Comment: You did not initialize `CORSFilter` bean in `web.xml`.

Comment: do you have an example. here it does not mention any change to web.xml https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html

Comment: The full exception stack trace would have been helpful

Answer (score 0):

I was solving a similar issue. I tried several approaches and here is the setting that works best if anybody else needs it.

SpringSecurity: 4.2.0.RELEASE. All server's API calls are prefixed with `/api/` path

**Spring security context:**

```
<http use-expressions='true'>
<!-- unrelated code skipped for brevity -->
<cors configuration-source-ref="corsSource"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="corsSource" class="org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource">
    <beans:property name="corsConfigurations">
        <util:map>
            <beans:entry key="/api/**">
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration">
                    <beans:property name="allowCredentials" value="true"/>
                    <beans:property name="allowedHeaders">
                        <beans:list>
                            <beans:value>Authorization</beans:value>
                            <beans:value>Content-Type</beans:value>
                        </beans:list>
                    </beans:property>
                    <beans:property name="exposedHeaders">
                        <beans:list>
                            <beans:value>Account-Locked</beans:value>
                            <beans:value>Account-Disabled</beans:value>
                            <beans:value>Bad-Credentials</beans:value>
                        </beans:list>
                    </beans:property>
                    <beans:property name="allowedMethods">
                        <beans:list>
                            <beans:value>POST</beans:value>
                            <beans:value>GET</beans:value>
                            <beans:value>OPTIONS</beans:value>
                        </beans:list>
                    </beans:property>
                    <beans:property name="allowedOrigins" value="http://localhost:3000"/>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:entry>
        </util:map>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

And in my **dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:cors>
    <mvc:mapping path="/api/**"
                 allowed-origins="http://localhost:3000"
                 allow-credentials="true"
                 allowed-methods="GET, OPTIONS"
    />
</mvc:cors>
```

Remember to change `allowed-origins` as well as `allowedHeaders` (= headers client is allowed to attach to request), `exposedHeaders` (= headers the server is allowed to attach to its response) and `allowedMethods`.

To keep sessions for authorized users I have to add `allowCredentials` property in Spring Security configuration and also to set `withCredentials` flag to `true` in JavaScript calls. I used *axios* so if you use another library, the flag may be named differently.